# R Studio Server: Multiple AWS EC2 Nodes

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I can run code in parallel in R Studio using the ForEach and DoSnow packages. I can easily fire up a 32 core AWS EC2 instance running R Studio Server and run code in parallel using the following code:

```
cl<-makeCluster(32) 
registerDoSNOW(cl)
foreach () %dopar% {}
```

However, the max number of cores on a single AWS EC2 instance is 32. How can I use the same exact code across multiple AWS EC2 nodes and utilize all the cores?

For example, let's say I want to run the same code in parallel across 4 AWS EC2, which would use 128 cores, instances like this:

```
cl<-makeCluster(128) 
registerDoSNOW(cl)
foreach () %dopar% {}
```

Is there some easy way to 'tie' multiple EC2 instances together so that R Studio Server, ForEach, and DoSnow see these 128 cores as if it were one EC2 instance?

Comment: This is off-topic because it's not about statistics.

Comment: Where should it be posted?

Comment: It seems to be on-topic for Stack Overlow. I flagged your question, my guess is that it'll be migrated there for you.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Did you ever figure out if this is possible?